# How can I generate random text file with random content and size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    class RandomTests
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }

        static List<string> listv;
        public static void GenerateRandomStrings()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(20, 1000); i++)
            {
                string rand = RandomString(20);
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
            }

            listv = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(item => item.Text)
                                 .ToList();
        }

        private void UsageExample()
        {
            GenerateRandom(5, 1, 6);
        }

        public static List<int> GenerateRandom(int count)
        {
            return GenerateRandom(count, 0, Int32.MaxValue);
        }

        // Note, max is exclusive here!
        public static List<int> GenerateRandom(int count, int min, int max)
        {

            //  initialize set S to empty
            //  for J := N-M + 1 to N do
            //    T := RandInt(1, J)
            //    if T is not in S then
            //      insert T in S
            //    else
            //      insert J in S
            //
            // adapted for C# which does not have an inclusive Next(..)
            // and to make it from configurable range not just 1.

            if (max <= min || count < 0 ||
                    // max - min > 0 required to avoid overflow
                    (count > max - min && max - min > 0))
            {
                // need to use 64-bit to support big ranges (negative min, positive max)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Range " + min + " to " + max +
                        " (" + ((Int64)max - (Int64)min) + " values), or count " + count + " is illegal");
            }

            // generate count random values.
            HashSet<int> candidates = new HashSet<int>();

            // start count values before max, and end at max
            for (int top = max - count; top < max; top++)
            {
                // May strike a duplicate.
                // Need to add +1 to make inclusive generator
                // +1 is safe even for MaxVal max value because top < max
                if (!candidates.Add(random.Next(min, top + 1)))
                {
                    // collision, add inclusive max.
                    // which could not possibly have been added before.
                    candidates.Add(top);
                }
            }

            // load them in to a list, to sort
            List<int> result = candidates.ToList();

            // shuffle the results because HashSet has messed
            // with the order, and the algorithm does not produce
            // random-ordered results (e.g. max-1 will never be the first value)
            for (int i = result.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int k = random.Next(i + 1);
                int tmp = result[k];
                result[k] = result[i];
                result[i] = tmp;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

For now I'm using only the GenerateRandomStrings() in Form1.
but now I ant to generate random text files with random content and size.
for example 100MB or 100GB files sizes with random content.

The files sizes should be from bytes to giga bytes. can be 1b file or 100GB file.

and then add the files to the listview as items like doing in the GenerateRandomStrings() function.

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
```

the same idea to add generated text files with random content and sizes.

Comment: Please do not use static functions that change static fields. Argumetns and return values - that is how you should be doing static functions. Once you got a function that returns a string (rather then this mess), it becomes trivial as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates a file, with size defined by the user and *filled* with random text,

```
Console.WriteLine("Give file size in bytes");
var fileSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var buffer = new byte[fileSize];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
var text = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
File.WriteAllText("/home/path/to/file/randomtext.txt", text);
```

Note: I am using Linux so you wanna change that path.